# How to get Scrollbar notifications from a TMemo control?

Tags: vcl, message, mousewheel, tmemo, c++builder-xe3

I have a VCL `TMemo` control and need to be notified every time the text is scrolled. There is no *`OnScroll`* event and the scroll messages doesn't seem to propagate up to the parent form.

Any idea of how to get the notification?
As a last resort I can place an external `TScrollBar` and update the `TMemo` in the *`OnScroll`* event, but then I have to keep them in sync when I move the cursor or scroll the mouse wheel in `TMemo`...

Comment: AFAICT, you'd have to write your own descendant and override the `WndProc` to catch `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` messages, and then do what you need in response to them.

Comment: @KenWhite, this isn't a Delphi application... I have changed back the tags.

Comment: Your tags didn't initially indicate it wasn't Delphi. It merely said VCL, which *is* Delphi. The answer is the same, though.

Comment: Well, VCL is C++ Builder too ;)

Comment: :-) Well, no. It can be used from C++ Builder, but all of the source code for the VCL is written in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass the Memo's `WindowProc` property at runtime to catch all of messages sent to the Memo, eg:

```
private:
    TWndMethod PrevMemoWndProc;
    void __fastcall MemoWndProc(TMessage &Message);
```

```
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    PrevMemoWndProc = Memo1->WindowProc;
    Memo1->WindowProc = MemoWndProc;
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::MemoWndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    switch (Message.Msg)
    {
        case CN_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (reinterpret_cast<TWMCommand&>(Message).NotifyCode)
            {
                case EN_VSCROLL:
                {
                    //...
                    break;
                }

                case EN_HSCROLL:
                {
                    //...
                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        case WM_HSCROLL:
        {
            //...
            break;
        }

        case WM_VSCROLL:
        {
            //...
            break;
        }
    }

    PrevMemoWndProc(Message);
}
```

Comment: I do get in messages but none of them are any SCROLL messages. I get Notifycode 0x0602 (WParamHi) if I press the memo scrollbar's Up and down buttons, no other CN_COMMANDS.

Comment: @MaxKielland: NotifyCode 0x0602 is `EN_VSCROLL` (`EN_HSCROLL` is 0x0601).

Comment: Thank you! The code was optimized away for some reason. When I did a more proper implementation it worked fine. By using the WM_xSCROLL messages I captured all the scrollbar behaviours,not only the arrow buttons. However, is there a way to also capture when the memo scrolls due to cursor movements? The scrollbar is updated but I don't get any scroll bar messages. I tried to listen for SBM_SETPOS but I guess it is sent directly to the embedded scrollbar. In worst case I guess I have to listen to the Key down events.

Comment: Good example for using `TWinControl`'s `WindowProc` property.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a interposer class to handle the `WM_VSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLL` messages and the  [`EN_VSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761689%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`EN_HSCROLL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification codes (exposed through the WM_COMMAND message).

Try this sample

```
type
  TMemo  = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TMemo)
  private
   procedure CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
   procedure WMVScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
   procedure WMHScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
  end;

  TForm16 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form16: TForm16;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


{ TMemo }

procedure TMemo.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
begin
   case Message.NotifyCode of
    EN_VSCROLL : OutputDebugString('EN_VSCROLL');
    EN_HSCROLL : OutputDebugString('EN_HSCROLL');
   end;

   inherited ;
end;

procedure TMemo.WMHScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll);
begin
   OutputDebugString('WM_HSCROLL') ;
   inherited;
end;

procedure TMemo.WMVScroll(var Msg: TWMHScroll);
begin
   OutputDebugString('WM_HSCROLL') ;
   inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using C++ Builder, but I will see if I can translate your example...

Comment: Interposer classes do not work in C++.  But you can subclass the `WindowProc` property of a standard `TMemo` component at runtime.

Comment: Just a tiny correction: `WM_VSCROLL` in the `TMemo.WMVScroll` procedure (now there is a `WM_HSCROLL`).